# My Caesar's Algorithm implementation in CS50 is incorrect

Tags: c, cs50

The first part is just to check that the key is a positive number.
I used the exact formula that was given in the problem.

ignore this part.!>>>

//*More formally, Caesar’s algorithm (i.e., cipher) encrypts messages by “rotating” each letter by  positions. More formally, if p is some plaintext (i.e., an unencrypted message),  is the ℎ character in  and k  is a secret key (i.e., a non-negative integer), then each letter, , in the ciphertext*//<<<

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int convertToInt(string input);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string testKey= argv[1];
    int key= convertToInt(testKey);

    if(argc>2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(testKey); i++)
        {
            if(testKey[i]<48||testKey[i]>57)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if(key<0)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    string phrase= get_string("plaintext:  ");

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(phrase); i++)
    {
        if((int)phrase[i]>='a'&&(int)phrase[i]<='z')
        {
            phrase[i]=(((phrase[i]- 'a')+ key)%26) +'a';
        }
        if((int)phrase[i]>='A'&&(int)phrase[i]<='Z')
        {
            phrase[i]=(((phrase[i]- 'A')+ key)%26) +'A';
        }
    }
    printf("chiphertext: %s \n", phrase);

}

int convertToInt(string input)
{
    int convertedValue=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(input); i++)
    {
        convertedValue=convertedValue* 10+ (int)input[i];
    }
    return convertedValue;
}
```

---

The first part is just to check that the key is a positive number.
I used the exact formula that was given in the problem.

Comment: `convertedValue = convertedValue * 10 + input[i] - '0';`

Comment: OT: You need the check `if(argc>2)` *before* you use `argv[1]`.

Comment: @alex21  This statement convertedValue=convertedValue* 10+ (int)input[i]; is wrong. Moreover there is no check whether the string starts with the sign character '-'. Instead of the for loop you could use for exam[e standard function atoi.

Comment: OT: Don 't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the character `'0'`, use the actual character instead. And if you want to check if a character is a digit, use [the standard `isdigit` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit). Similarly when checking for letters, there are functions for that as well. And to convert to lower- or upper-case.

Comment: And please note that the expression `(((phrase[i]- 'a')+ key)%26) +'a'` is very specific to ASCII encoding, which is *not* part of the C specification. There are systems still in active use that uses encoding where that will fail.

Comment: Lastly about your problem (and which have been touched upon by other comments), there are no known encoding where `'0' == 0` (for example). You do seem to know that, to be able to create your digit-check loop. So I assume it simply slipped your mind when doing the conversion?

Comment: What's the intention of "Ignore this part!" in your question? Why did you include it if you want it ignored?

Comment: "I used the exact formula that was given in the problem" then the problem statement is wrong. Talk to your teaching staff and ask them why their formula is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In checking the unanswered issues, I was a bit surprised that this issue had not been closed, since it has a lot of down votes.  So, in lieu of clicking to close this issue, I hesitantly offer up the following refactored code that attempts to address the positive key value along with formulating a simplified letter shift function, utilizing conventional functions within the standard string and character function sets.  Quite frankly, I wasn't sure what was the ultimate issue here, so I did an end-to-end analysis of the code to work on refactoring the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALPHABET 26                         /* Denoting that this program is working with the standard English alphabet */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char testKey[100];
    char phrase[100];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy(testKey, argv[1]);               /* Replacing CS50 functions with conventional string functions */

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(testKey); i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(testKey[i]) == 0)        /* This would ensure that all of the characters in the argument are digits and thus would be a positive value */
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key - all digits\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int key = atoi(testKey);                /* Use conventional "string to integer" functions in lieu of custom "convertToInt" function */

    key = key % ALPHABET;                   /* Perform the modulo operation to get the value between 0 and 25 */

    printf("key: %d\n", key);               /* Just validating the resulting key shift */

    if(key<0)                               /* Should not occur due to the previous "isdigit()" testing - "-" is not a digit */
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Plaintext...: ");               /* Substituted method of acquiring the text since not utilizing CS50 */
    if(fgets(phrase, 99, stdin) == NULL)
        strcpy(phrase, "Hello World");      /* Fallback text just in case nothing is entered */

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(phrase); i++)
    {
        if(phrase[i] == 10)                 /* "fgets" will return the newline character, so this needs to be changed to the terminator varlue */
        {
            phrase[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(phrase); i++)
    {
        if((phrase[i] >= 'a' && phrase[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            if ((phrase[i] + key) > 'z')    /* Protect from overflow */
                phrase[i] -= ALPHABET;
            phrase[i] += key;
        }
        if((phrase[i] >= 'A' && phrase[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            if ((phrase[i] + key) > 'Z')    /* Protect from overflow */
                phrase[i] -= ALPHABET;
            phrase[i] += key;
        }
    }
    printf("Ciphertext..: %s \n", phrase);

    return 0;
}
```

Following are some key points:

- First off, standard/conventional methods were utilized in acquiring string information in lieu of the "CS50" functionality; not to denigrate these functions, but because I do not have that toolkit installed, and it demonstrates more common methodology in acquiring variable input.
- It should be pointed out as noted in the good comments, that this program is set up to perform the text scrambling for the English alphabet and would not work for other alphabets (e.g. the definition of the constant "ALPHABET").
- Since standard string and character functions were being included, it seemed simpler to just utilize functions such as "isdigit()" as noted in the good comments in lieu of crafting a custom test, which as a by-product ensures that the entered key value is a positive number, and utilizing the "atoi()" function to acquire the integer value in lieu of having to utilize a custom function.
- And since this program is referencing the twenty-six character English alphabet, it was simplest to derive the key shift value up front prior to acquiring the text to be scrambled, which makes the actual shifting within the "for" loop simpler.

With all of that, following were some sample tests of the code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Caesar/bin/Release$ ./Caesar
Usage: ./caesar key
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Caesar/bin/Release$ ./Caesar -111
Usage: ./caesar key - all digits
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Caesar/bin/Release$ ./Caesar 111
key: 7
Plaintext...: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country
Ciphertext..: Uvd pz aol aptl mvy hss nvvk tlu av jvtl av aol hpk vm aolpy jvbuayf
```

Spot checking the derived letters for the encrypted text, the ensuing letters matched up to what would be expected with the key shift.

If you are required to utilize the "CS50" functions for acquiring variable input, go ahead and keep that code as is.  In any regard, it would be beneficial to reference some standard "C" programming tutorials where it pertains to string and character functionality.