# The isupper() function appears to not identify certain letters (A, B, C, D, E, F, Z) as uppercase for some reason. Why is that so?

Tags: c

I am currently working on a practice problem which intends to encrypt some plaintext with a quite
simple algorithm. All alphabetical characters are to be encrypted, that's why I'm passing each character of my plaintext to the isupper() function to determine whether or not the character should be encrypted.
Weirdly, every character I'm checking seems to get processed as intended except of the letters "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" & "Z". I did some testing and whenever I check those characters, the else clause is run and not the intended else if clause, as if the given characters aren't identified as uppercase by the else if clause with the isupper() function.

That's my code (the problem is within the rotate() function on the very bottom):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Prototypes
bool only_digits(string s);
char rotate(char c, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // In case of improper usage, print feedback and return with 1
    // Check for single command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Make sure the provided input is a decimal
    if (only_digits(argv[1]) != true)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Store privided key in k (Convert to int)
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Prompt user for plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Encrypt plaintext
    int len = strlen(plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        plaintext[i] = rotate(plaintext[i], k);
    }

    // Output ciphertext and return from main
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", plaintext);
    return 0;
}

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    bool condition = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false)
        {
            condition = false;
        }
    }

    if (condition == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

char rotate(char c, int key)
{
    // Prepare for wrapping around
    key = key % 26;

    // Check for alphabetical letter
    if (isalpha(c) == false)
    {
        return c;
    }

    // Hardcoding because the following letters were for some reasons not recognized as uppercase from the isupper function
    else if (isupper(c) == true || c == 'A' || c == 'B' || c == 'C' || c == 'D' || c == 'E' || c == 'F' || c == 'Z')
    {
        return (char) (((int) c - 65 + key) % 26 + 65);
    }
    else
    {
        return (char) (((int) c - 97 + key) % 26 + 97);
    }
}
```

As I said, from my testing it seems like that only the letters "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" & "Z" are causing the issue. I identified that the else if clause isn't run for them although it actually should and instead the else clause runs. I also checked what character I'm passing to the `isupper()` function as `char c` by printing it one line earlier and I can confirm that the right (uppercase) characters are stored in the variable `c`.
I really have no idea why this is happening. I know that the issue most likely can't be the standard library function `isupper()` but I have no clue what else it could be. I'm new to coding, maybe I overlooked something obvious. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `isupper` doesn't return a boolean, it returns a zero/non-zero, no idea if this is the problem, but it may be, as true has a specific value which may be different to the return value from `isupper`

Comment: Have you consider that maybe in those cases the program does execute the first `if (isalpha(c) == false)` and so it does not execute the `else` part?

Comment: It appears to work getting rid of `true` and `false`. https://onlinegdb.com/nUaztCn1ly

Comment: It's rare to test `if (condition == true)` or `if (condition == false)` in *any* programming language. Use `if (condition)` or `if (!condition)` (or as appropriate in other languages).

Comment: @Nickistired You _are_ correct. The `ctype.h` functions index into a table of (e.g.) `unsigned short __ctype_attr[256];` These are bit masks defined in an `enum`: `_ISlower = 1 << 1` Then, `#define islower(c) (__ctype_attr[c] & _ISlower)`

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks!, that does make me more confident in the dupe I found, which funnily enough also points to a CS50 situation

Comment: @Nickistired can confirm too, testing on Linux I get `256` for `isupper('A')` (whereas `true` is just `1`).

Comment: FYI, this is almost identical to this issue "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77383564/my-caesars-algorithm-implementation-in-cs50-is-incorrect/77391527#77391527", for which I went ahead and developed a refactored version of the program.

Comment: OT: The timorousness of `only_digits()` gives me the willies! (@jarmod Or, simply `return false;` inside the first `if()` and `return true;` if string is exhausted...)

Comment: In C it is quite dangerous to test for explicit equality/inequality with `true`, as any non-zero value is true. At least `false == 0`.

Comment: OT: `./caesar 2147483648` leads to `atoi( argv[1] ) % 26`, leads to `key` being `-24`... The encrypted output is Ka-ka... Go research `strtol()` and don't use `atoi()` anymore. With `strtol()`, you can get the conversion and verify the string is only digits at the same time. Then, add a conditional that rejects foolish keys given by users (like me) who seek to break your program...

Comment: @kevin-sekol Consider simplifying code `bool only_digits(string s) { while (isdigit(*s)) { s++; } return *s == 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem is `isupper(c)` does not return a boolean value, it returns an `int` that is `0` if `c` is not an uppercase letter and non zero otherwise.  The test `if (isupper(c) == true ...)` is incorrect, you should just write

```
    if (isupper(c)) { ...
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Prototypes
bool only_digits(string s);
char rotate(char c, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // In case of improper usage, print feedback and return with 1
    // Check for single command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Make sure the provided input is a decimal
    if (!only_digits(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Store provided key in k (Convert to int in the range 0..25)
    int k = (strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) % 26 + 26) % 26;

    // Prompt user for plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // Encrypt plaintext
    int len = strlen(plaintext);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        plaintext[i] = rotate(plaintext[i], k);
    }

    // Output ciphertext and return from main
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", plaintext);
    return 0;
}

bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

char rotate(char c, int key)
{
    // Check for alphabetical letter
    if (!isalpha(c))
    {
        return c;
    }

    if (isupper(c))
    {
        return (char)(((int)c - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A');
    }
    else
    {
        return (char)(((int)c - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what fixed my code. Such a dumb mistake, should have checked the documentation earlier. Everything works as intended now.

Comment: I'm a malicious user who enters `./caesar 2147483648`... `atoi( argv[1] )%26` is `-24`... Things don't come out as expected!!

Comment: That's better! `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

Your conclusions are most likely wrong as it is very very unlikely standard library function to be so erratic.

run simple test:

```
int main(void)
{
    for(int c = 32; c < 127; c++)
    {
        printf("'%c' - is uppercase: %s\n", c, isupper(c) ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KKq8h63s9

and you will see that the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Generally do not compare the result of standard library function to `false` or `true` as they do not have to return `0` or `1` and default conversion rules will convert `bool` to int.

when checking if something is `true` you can

```
if(toupper(x))

if(toupper(x) != 0)

if(!!toupper(x) == true)
```

Comment: Assuming this is correct, this sort of thing should be pointed out in a comment instead; it demonstrates that the problem is not reproducible or is caused by a typo, and as such the question should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have a different opinion as it shows how to check the claims. IMO much more beneficial than just closing the question

Comment: That simply isn't how Stack Overflow works; this is **not a discussion forum** so we don't use the answer section to post things simply because they would help the OP with the original code - we use the answer section to answer the question that was asked, and only when that question meets the site's standards.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Re "*to answer the question that was asked*", Not exactly. It's quite common to address the actual problem instead of taking the question literally. The OP's problem is that they're not using `isupper` correctly, and 0__ showed how to use it correctly. (Would be better if 0__ realized and/or explained what was wrong with the OP's way, though.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hmmm, Some folks speak in plural, other do not.  It is often useful for  answers to approach the question from different angles to allow the OP (and others) a  point-of-view that works for them.